# Can I get the click event of this layout

Tags: android

I use the following RelativeLayout to display Fragment

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/readfile_relalayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my click listener is this, but this click listener is not take effect

```
readfile_relalayout.setOnClickListener {
    showMessage("Test1")
}
```

This is my fragment class

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pdf_frm, container, false)
    return view
}
```

After that, I will use the readfile_relalayout id to make the fragment use this layout as a container, but I have a new requirement, that is, I want to get the click event through the readfile_relalayout id. I have tried to add clickable = "true" to readfile_relalayout but this does not Solve my problem, hope you can help me

Comment: You should write clickLiseter on this

Comment: @ShaluTD Is the click listener added to readfile_relalayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try below:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pdf_frm, container, false)
    view.setOnClickListener {
      // write your code here
    }
    return view
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I bound NullPointerException to readfile_relalayout in the fragment

Comment: Please give onclicklistener to the outerview of your fragment. means you have inflated one layout there. take that layouts outerview and give clicklistener

Comment: I set the OnClickListener in the activity outside the fragment but he does not work, but if it is set in the fragment, a NullPointerException will appear

Comment: I mean inside fragment. you have layout inflated there rt? you should give clicklistener to that layout. Plz share your fragment class

Comment: ok, thanks, I have shared the onCreateView method in my fragment fragment, I will continue to provide if more is needed, thanks

Comment: I tried to add a layer of Linearlayout to readfile_relalayout, and set onclicklistener to linearlayout, but onclicklistener did not take effect

Comment: Updated answer. Please check now

Comment: oh no also is not effect